# What controls the brightness of the MCDU display and keys?

Tags: airbus

What brightness does the `brt` and `dim` on the right side of the `MCDU MENU` button change?
The brightness of the display, the keys or of both?
And if only one of them, what controls the other?
[image: mcdu]
<sub>(source: [skalarki-electronics.eu](https://www.skalarki-electronics.eu/images/skalarki/A320_MCDU_CS.jpg))</sub>

EDIT: As shown in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hzknF9qIUm4&t=63) video, the brigghtness knob turns just the display on/regulates it's brightness.
What changes the brightness of the keys (They seem to be lit befor the MCDU is turned on)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brightness of the keys is controlled together with the rest of the pedestal via the "INTEG LT MAIN PNL & PED" knob on the lower pedestal below the capt ACP.

Answer (score 4):

These buttons are to increase and decrease brightness of [MCDU](https://aerospace.honeywell.com/en/products/cockpit-systems/multi-function-control-and-display-unit). Also, they are used to turn on and off the unit.

As explained [here](http://airbusone.blogspot.com/2013/05/auto-flight-general.html):

> BRT AND DIM KEYS
>   Control the light intensity of the entire MCDU. MCDU power up is performed 
>   with the BRT key and MCDU shut down is performed with the DIM key.

And [here](http://forum.aerosoft.com/index.php?/topic/81752-left-mcdu-screen-black/):

> Repeatedly clicking on the "BRT" (the top of the paddle switch) will
>   switch the unit on and increase the brightness. The reverse is also
>   true. Repeatedly clicking on the "DIM" (the bottom of the paddle
>   switch) will decrease the brightness and switch the unit off.

Comment: Is there some sort of warning between the lowest "Dim" setting and "Off"? I can see someone (me in particular - I like my dash display very dim), thinking "that's still too bright, let me hit Dim again" and turning the thing off because it's already at its lowest setting.